# Create Android virtual device using shell on GCE instance

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04, android-virtual-device

I am trying to deploy an Android virtual device on a GCP Computing Engine instance. I used the following command:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install android-sdk`

In order to install the Android SDK, which is installed in the following directory: `/usr/lib/android-sdk`. I can run adb without any problem, but I need to deploy an avd in order to perform adb actions. Is there a way to deploy an avd using the shell? Or is there a way to connect adb via TCPIP without having a device connected?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android SDK installed on your machine, go to the root of the Android sdk directory (on an UNIX system it usually is ~/Library/Android/sdk) and run the following:

1) `cd emulator/` 
2) `./emulator list-avds` to display a list of available images (that you created/imported)
3) `./emulator -avd foo` (where foo is the name of your emulator)

You can visit the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) for mor details.
Hope that helps.